# Getting empty file in mail attachment

Tags: php, email

Im trying to send mail from my server with file attachment, my problem is that the mail arrives with everything except the content of the attached file, i tried pdf,docx,jpeg.... no matter what format i attach, ill get blank/empty file.

im running wamp server with sendmail(), here is the php script:

```
<?php

$email = $_GET['page'];
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {

$file = $path.$filename;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
//$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('./payDoc.pdf', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
//$header .= $attachment."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";

// Messages for testing only, nobody will see them unless this script URL is visited manually
if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
    echo "Message sent!";
} else {
    echo "ERROR sending message.";
}
```

}

```
//File  attach
$my_file = "payDoc.pdf";
$my_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/connect_android/include/"; 

//email is FROM
$my_name    = "Android Store";
$my_mail    = "demo@gmail.com";
$my_replyto = "demo@gmail.com";

//email is going TO
$to_email   = $email;  

// Subject of email
$my_subject = "Order details has arrived ";



$message = "Please fill the file attached,
some text to add
goes here";

// send email
mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, $to_email, $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $message);
```

Comment: are you getting any error in your php code ? did u debug ?  **error_reporting(1);**

Comment: nope i get Message sent in postman, the mail is transferred well, the file attached is the only problem, he is blank.

Comment: Generally, it's link to the path of the file. So try to see if your file path is good.

Comment: i did echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/connect_android/include/"; the path is ok :(

Comment: You get file size in $file_size?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using PHPmailer?
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Literally had this same problem 5mins ago, turned out i missed adding this to my opening form tag.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```